# nfs server getting many rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: sent only 700260 when sending 1048708 bytes - shutting down socket

Tags: nfs, performance-tuning

System is running CentOS 7.3, serving files over both ethernet and infiniband, but the vast majority of traffic is over infiniband

I just stood up a new file server that is now generating large numbers of the following error:

```
[2007827.701033] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: sent only 618872 when sending 1048708 bytes - shutting down socket
[2007835.313884] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: sent only 75908 when sending 1048708 bytes - shutting down socket
```

I increased the tcp_rmem and wmem to a max of 32mb, but the problem persists

```
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 33554432 
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 33554432
```

Are there any other ways I could tune this to get around the issue?

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/) reports some more suggestions, including increasing the NIC txqueuelen. These suggestions are mainly aimed at high latency networks, however I noticed that under Fedora24 Infiniband interfaces get by default a lower txqueuelen value (256) than other interfaces (1000), so the txquelen suggestion, besides the others, may also make sense in this case.

The modern way to do so is actually:

`ip link set ib0 txqueuelen 10000`

After following the suggestions on the indicated page, nfs-on-Infiniband errors of the type you reported have ceased in my nfs server.

Comment: That's a nice first answer. Welcome to ServerFault.